# Formula to to calculate number of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, percentages

I'm trying to find a formula for counting number combinations in a set. For example: how many ways can 4 numbers, each between 1 and 6, be added together to get the sum of 16? I apologize if I am not phrasing this well. I've been doing these combinations individually; I just finished writing out all 1296 combinations of 4 numbers 1-6, and the idea of writing out all 7776 combinations of 5 numbers 1-6 to find the percentage of each number 5-30 in that 7776 makes me want to cry. I've tried to find the answer on my own, but I'm just stumped.

Comment: look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: just write down those that make sense starting with 6: 6+6+3+1 no other possibility with two 6. so one 6 one 5 next. 6+5+4+1, 6+5+3+2, no other possibilities with 6 and 5, take 6 and 4... it's relatively fast to be honest.

Comment: @Vasya I'm not sure if that applies quite so nicely to this scenario, since the scenario posited doesn't allow *any* nonnegative/positive integer, but within tighter restrictions. Unless I'm overlooking something obvious

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I assume you want integers as your solutions, and that order is not important.*

This method is fairly general but possibly overkill and above your level, and you'll perhaps find yourself using calculus results if going by hand. However, I don't myself know of any easier method offhand that has the same generality.

To recollection this method can be brought into the case where order *is* relevant by using exponential generating function; the overall approach is fairly similar.

---

Generally, I often see generating functions as a mean of solving such "combinations with restrictions" problems. This isn't a general "formula" to solving them, though, so much as a method.

For example, using your scenario, we want the number of integer solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 16$$

where $1 \le x_i \le 6$ for $i=1,...,4$. To approach this by generating functions, first we define a polynomial for the restrictions on each variable. Define the polynomial corresponding to $x_i$ by

$$P_i(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} x^n$$

where the $n$'s used are tied to the allowed values for $x_i$. Thus, if $x_i$ can be any even integer, $P_i(x) = x^0 + x^2 + x^4 + ...$ (an infinite sum; we often let $x^0=1$ for simplicity). If $x_i$ can be, say, any prime from $2$ to $11$, we'd have $P_i(x) = x^2 + x^3 + x^5 + x^7 + x^{11}$.

*(Note: sometimes, if the pattern permits, we might leave $P_i$ as an infinite sum instead of finite. This can make calculations easier but it simply all depends, and cannot always be done.)*

Relevant to your scenario, each $P_i$ is $P_i(x) = 1+x+x^2 + ... + x^6$. Then we define a generating function $g$ by

$$g(x) = \prod_i P_i(x)$$

In your case, we take the product of the four polynomials and thus have

$$g(x) = (1+x+x^2+...+x^6)^4$$

Okay, so what is the importance of $g$? Let's say we were in the more general scenario, seeking the number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+...+x_n = r$. Then we would construct the $P_i$ and $g$ as above, and then we would do whatever manipulations we can to get $g$ into the form of

$$g(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n$$

for whatever values $a_n$ are. Then, after doing so, we find the coefficient of $x^r$ (i.e. $a_r$); that will be the desired number of solutions. Note, in your case, $r=16$, so we seek the coefficient of $x^{16}$ in the product above.

We can arguably do this by hand, for example, or use various formulas and identities to make the sum nicer: convenient ones include the binomial expansion, (finite and infinite) geometric series, and generalized binomial series. For example, in your case, the finite geometric series gives us

$$g(x) = \left(\frac{1-x^{7}}{1-x} \right)^4 = (1-x^{7})^4 \cdot (1-x)^{-4}$$

We then can apply binomial expansion and the infinite geometric series to the left and right factors respectively:

$$g(x) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{4} \binom{4}{k}((-x)^7)^k \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{4+k-1}{4-1} x^k \right) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{4} \binom{4}{k}(-1)^{k}x^{7k} \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k+3}{3} x^k \right)$$

and then the rules of polynomial multiplication, when focusing on $x^{16}$'s term, give the result.

Alternatively, you could just dump the polynomial into a calculator, e.g. Wolfram Alpha, and see if that helps. In this case, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(+sum+from+k%3D1+to+6+of+x%5Ek+)%5E4) gives an expanded form of the polynomial, with $125$ as the coefficient of $x^{16}$.

Answer (score 0):

(to avoid confusion of word "number" between "number of ways" and "get $6$ using $3$ numbers" lets say that we want to get some sum using $n$ coins, each coin has nominal from $1$ to $6$)

You can greatly simplify the problem by noting that if you add another coin you don't need to remember all ways to get some sum from previous coins - only the number of such ways.

So, to start - there obviously is exactly $1$ way to get each sum from $1$ to $6$ using one coin. What if we use two coins?

It's impossible to get $1$ from two coins. To get $2$, we need to get $1$ from the first coin and $1$ from the second, thus 1 way to get $2$.

To get, say, $4$, we can get $1$ from the first and $3$ from the second, $2$ from the first and $2$ from the second, or $3$ from the first and $1$ from the second - thus $3$ ways.

So far this is not better then just list all pairs. But what when we switch to three coins?

To get, say, $7$ from $3$ coins, we can get $2$ from the first two and $5$ from the last, or $3$ and $4$, or $4$ and $3$, or $5$ and $2$, or $6$ and $1$. For example, we already know that there are $5$ ways to get $6$ from two coins - but note that we don't need to list all of them again when we calculate number of ways for $3$ coins.

This way to switch from $n$ coins to $n + 1$ will require just $6 \cdot 5n$ operations, instead of $6^n$ - it's already manageable by hands.

And we can improve it even further! Lets say that for any sum from $3$ to $18$ we know number of ways to get this sum from $2$ or $3$ coins. Then if we want to know number of ways to get say $10$ from $5$ coins, we can write all possible ways to split this $10$ into first $3$ and last $2$ coins, and then multiply corresponding number of ways from $3$ and $2$ coin problems.

Formally, if $f_n(k)$ is number of ways to get sum of $k$ using $n$ coins, the first solution uses $f_{n + 1}(k) = \sum_{i = 1}^6 f_n(k - i)$ ($i$ is nominal of the last coin), and the second $f_{n + m}(k) = \sum_{i=0}^k f_n(i) f_m(k - i)$ [the first is just special case of the second - $m = 1$].